# Why isn't a templetized UI Bootstrap popover displaying on my UI Grid cell

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover, angular-ui-grid

I have a simple [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) solution that renders a table using [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/). Whenever showing an attribute that is an array of values, I want to show the first element in the array and show a popover when the user clicks on the cell. I used [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to render the popover.

The software to show this template was stitched up as follows (See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HZAroVSvBbHvVadbkA6y?p=preview) for more details):

- The UI Grid Configuration (I want the popover to show for the entries in the roles column):

  ```
  $scope.gridOptionsPopoverTemplate = {
     columnDefs: [
       { name: 'name',    width:128},
       { name: 'balance', width:128},
       { name: 'city',    width:128},
       { name: 'roles',   width:128, field: 'roles', cellTemplate: 'iq_cellTemplate_2.html', cellClass: 'cellPopover'}
     ]
  };
  ```
- The cellTemplate definition, iq_cellTemplate_2.html, as follows:

  ```
  <div popover-template="iq_popoverTemplate.html" 
      popover-title='Title'
      popover-trigger="click" 
      popover-placement="right" 
      popover-append-to-body="true">{{grid.getCellValue(row, col)[0]}}
  </div>
  ```
- The template to render the roles in the popover, as follows:

  ```
  <div ng-repeat="role in grid.getCellValue(row, col)">
     <p>role</p>
  </div>
  ```

Unfortunately it does not work, with the observed behavior being that the popover is not rendered without any other observable symptom. You will also notice that the plunker has two sections, with the other section demonstrating that the popover is shown when, instead of using the popover-template directive, the popover directive is used instead.

One additional note, I have been able render the popover using the [Bootstrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers), , as shown in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BIbrfNt0U2dng3Src9DA?p=preview). It almost works, since in cases where the popover bleeds over the UI Grid viewport (overlay: scroll;) the portion that bleeds over is hidden.

The popover can be shown if it append to an element outside the scope of the UI Grid viewport, which is done by the UI Bootstrap when using the popover directive but fails when using the popover-template directive.

Before I write additional custom code to handle this I thought to ask whether anyone has any thoughts or suggestions. Thanks in advance for any your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this answer:

- [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) does not support it yet; see comments on the source code:

  ```
   /**
    * The following features are still outstanding: popup delay, animation as a
    * function, placement as a function, inside, support for more triggers than
    * just mouse enter/leave, html popovers, and selector delegatation.
  ```
- The [Bootstrap popover](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popover) supports the required behavior. I solved it by attaching the popovers to the body

  ```
   var popover = $(element).popover({
     trigger: 'hover',
     html: true,
     container: 'body',
     content: template,
     title: scope.title,
     placement: 'right'
   });
  ```